# Does integration by parts formula hold in $H^1(0,T,L^2(\Omega))$?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, parabolic-pde, banach-algebras, banach-lattices

Let $\Omega$ be an open set from $\mathbb{R}^N$. How can we prove that if $u,v\in H^1(0,T,L^2(\Omega))$ (in Bochner sense) then $(u\cdot v)'\in L^2(0,T,L^1(\Omega))$ with $(uv)'=u'v+v'u$ and the integration by parts formula holds:

$$\int_0^T u'v\ dt=u(T)v(T)-u(0)v(0)-\int_{0}^T uv'\ dt $$

?

I see this formula applied in this context, but I found no proof for it.

Comment: You can't. Did you perhaps mean that $u\cdot v \in H^1(0,T,L^1(\Omega))$? The product of two $L^2$ functions is generally not in $L^2$.

Comment: This is an exception. See, the book of Brezis, page 215.

Comment: It is not, Brezis p. 215 is about Sobolev functions on an interval which are automatically bounded and this is exactly what you need. In the question, $(uv)(t)$ is generically only an $L^1(\Omega)$ function and there is no real way out without further assumptions.

Comment: The statement is true and it is a generalization of Brezis, p. 215.

Comment: No, it is wrong for $\Omega = (0, 1)$ and $u(t,x) = v(t,x) = x^{-1/4}$.

Comment: Very interesting...I was wrong then by saying that $u\cdot v\in H^1(0,T,X)$. But I see the integration by parts applied in this context. Even in your example the integration by parts formula holds. For example in this course of G. Leoni, at page 86 he uses that in proving the maximum principle> http://giovannileoni.weebly.com/uploads/3/1/0/5/31054371/pde-ii-lectures-2014-05-02-signed.pdf

Comment: I have edited my post.

Comment: For the edited question to make sense you first have to specify what you mean by $(uv)'$ since, as pointed out by others, $uv$ does not take values in $X$, in general. Do you mean the distributiinal derivative of functions that take values in $L^1(\Omega)$?

Comment: Exactly. I corrected it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Could you specific where precisely you see a problem now? The product rule seems to follow from simply combining the following three things (i) the definition of the vector-valued weak derivative; (ii) testing against $L^\infty(\Omega)$-functions; (iii) using the product rule for scalar-valued Sobolev functions. The integration by part formula then follows from the product rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus (i.e., its version for vector-valued Sobolev functions).

Comment: I'm sorry...my limited knowledge does't allow me to see how you can reduce the problem to the product rule for scalar Sobolev functions (who are these functions? How are they obtained from $u,v$?). Also, I don't understand exactly what you mean by "testing against $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ - functions".

Comment: @JochenGlueck Can you detail a little bit, please?

Comment: See Proposition V.2.4.7 in *Linear and Quasilinear Parabolic Problems Volume I: Abstract Linear Theory* by Amann. (Choose $E_0 = E_1 = L^2(\Omega)$ and use the fundamental theorem of calculus in the resulting product rule; an interval is always "minimally smooth".)

Comment: @Hannes Thank you very, very much for your response!